# EditContactView not initializing when route is reached in Backbone.js app

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I'm building a Contact Manager in Backbone.js for learning purposes. There's a directory of contacts and when you click on it, it displays a block of more information of the contact. It also contains an edit button. Each contact clicked on displays the correct path.

Example:
/index.html#directory/3.

When you click on the edit button for that contact it goes to:

/index.html#directory/3/edit

Even though it reaches the route, the edit contact view is not initialized. It's definitely hitting the EditContact function in the ContactRouter when I console.log a test. I want to know what I need to do in order for it to be initialized. I'm not getting any javascript errors or any responses when I check in the Chrome inspector so I'm at a loss of where to proceed next. I appreciate any responses, thank you.

**App.js:**

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'collections/directory',
'views/index',
'views/contacts',
'views/directory',
'views/contact',
'views/edit_contact',
'models/contacts'
], function($, _, Backbone, Directory, IndexView, ContactsView, DirectoryView, ContactView, Contact, EditContactView){
    var contacts = [
                { id: 1, name: "Jason", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" },
                { id: 2, name: "Dad", address: "555 Fairfax St, Fairfax, VA 22032", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" },
                { id: 3, name: "Jose", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "friend" },
                { id: 4, name: "John", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "colleague" },
                { id: 5, name: "Grandpa", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" },
                { id: 6, name: "Kevin", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "colleague" },
                { id: 7, name: "Eugene", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "friend" },
                { id: 8, name: "Mom", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" }
    ];
// Routes
var ContactRouter =  Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '' : 'home',
        'directory': 'viewDirectory',
        'directory/:id': 'viewContact',
        'directory/:id/edit': 'editContact'
    },
    home: function(){
        var home = new IndexView();
        return home;
    },
    viewDirectory: function(){
        var directory = new DirectoryView(contacts);
    },
    viewContact: function(id){
        var all_contacts = new Directory(contacts);
        var contact = new ContactView({model: all_contacts.get({id: id})});
    },
    editContact: function(id){
        var all_contacts = new Directory(contacts);
        var contact = new EditContactView({model: all_contacts.get({id: id})});
    }
});

var appRouter = new ContactRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

});

**edit_contact.js**

```
define([
  // These are path alias that we configured in our bootstrap
  'jquery',     // lib/jquery
  'underscore', // lib/underscore
  'backbone',    // lib/backbone
  'collections/directory',
], function($, _, Backbone, Directory){
    var EditContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $(".editContact"),
        tagName: "div",
        className: "edit-container",
        template: $("#editContactTemplate").html(),
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('test2');
        }
    });
    return EditContactView;
});
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="intro-container"></div>
    <script id="introTemplate" type="text/template">
        <h1>Welcome to Contact Manager</h1>
        <a href="<%= contactLink %>">Click Here to begin...</a>
    </script>
    <div id="contacts"></div>
    <script id="contactsTemplate" type="text/template">
        <img src="<%= photo %>" alt="<%= name %>" class="avatar" />
        <a href="#directory/<%= id %>"><h1><%= name %> <span><%= type %></span></h1></a>
    </script>
    <div class="contact"></div>
    <script id="contactTemplate" type="text/template">
        <h1><%= name %> <span><%= type %></span></h1>
        <div><%= address %></div>
        <dl>
            <dt>Tel:</dt><dd><%= tel %></dd>
            <dt>Email:</dt><dd><a href="mailto:<%=email %>"><%= email %></a></dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#directory/<%= id %>/edit" class="edit_contact">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </script>
    <div class="editContact"></div>
    <script id="editContactTemplate" type="text/template">
        <h2>Edit Contact</h2>
        <label>Name:</label><input type='text' name='name' value=''/><br/>
        <label>Address:</label><input type='text' name='address' value=''/><br/>
        <label>Tel:</label><input type='text' name='tel' value=''/>
        <label>Email:</label><input type='text' name='email' value=''/><br/>
        <label>Type:</label>
        <select>
            <option value='family'>family</option>
            <option value='friend'>friend</option>
            <option value='colleage'>colleague</option>
        </select><br/>
        <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit' />"
    </script>
</body>
```

**UPDATED App.js****

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/directory',
    'views/index',
    'views/contacts',
    'views/directory',
    'views/contact',
    'views/edit_contact',
    'models/contacts'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, Directory, IndexView, ContactsView, DirectoryView, ContactView, EditContactView, Contact){
        var contacts = [
                    { id: 1, name: "Jason", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Dad", address: "555 Fairfax St, Fairfax, VA 22032", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" },
                    { id: 3, name: "Jose", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "friend" },
                    { id: 4, name: "John", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "colleague" },
                    { id: 5, name: "Grandpa", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" },
                    { id: 6, name: "Kevin", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "colleague" },
                    { id: 7, name: "Eugene", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "friend" },
                    { id: 8, name: "Mom", address: "1, a street, a town, a city, AB12 3CD", tel: "0123456789", email: "anemail@me.com", type: "family" }
        ];
    // Routes
    var ContactRouter =  Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '' : 'home',
            'directory': 'viewDirectory',
            'directory/:id': 'viewContact',
            'directory/:id/edit': 'editContact'
        },
        home: function(){
            var home = new IndexView();
            return home;
        },
        viewDirectory: function(){
            var directory = new DirectoryView(contacts);
        },
        viewContact: function(id){
            var all_contacts = new Directory(contacts);
            var contact = new ContactView({model: all_contacts.get({id: id})});
        },
        editContact: function(id){
            var all_contacts = new Directory(contacts);
            var contact = new EditContactView({model: all_contacts.get({id: id})});
        }
    });

    var appRouter = new ContactRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();

});
```

The problem was the order of the arguments of the definition function for requirejs
Instead of: *..Contact, EditViewContact){*
It should be: *..EditViewContact, Contact){*

Comment: does `console.log('test2')` trigger?

Comment: no it did not, but I did get it fixed though. It had to do with the order of the arguments in the definition function.